# Error while Uploading Multiple files

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

Hi when I was trying to upload files it shows the path is not virtual it shows with "E:/"+dest path so can anyone suggest how to upload my file in dest path below is the VB code

```
  Protected Sub Upload_Files(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' CHECK IF ANY FILE HAS BEEN SELECTED.
    If fileUpload.HasFile Then
        Dim iUploadedCnt As Integer = 0
        Dim iFailedCnt As Integer = 0
        Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files

        lblFileList.Text = "Select <b>" & hfc.Count & "</b> file(s)"

        If hfc.Count <= 10 Then             ' 10 FILES RESTRICTION.
            For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
                Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(i)
                If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
                    If Not File.Exists(Server.MapPath("\\Destinationpath\testing") & _
                            Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)) Then

                        Dim objDir As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("\\Destinationpath\testing"))

                        Dim objFI As FileInfo() = _
                            objDir.GetFiles(Replace(Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName), _
                                Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName), "") & ".*")
                        If objFI.Length > 0 Then
                            ' CHECK IF FILE WITH SAME NAME EXISTS (IGNORING THE EXTENTIONS).
                            For Each file As FileInfo In objFI
                                If Replace(objFI(0).Name, Path.GetExtension(objFI(0).Name), "") = _
                                    Replace(Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName),
                                        Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName), "") Then

                                    iFailedCnt = iFailedCnt + 1
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next
                        Else
                            ' SAVE THE FILE IN A FOLDER.
                            hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("\\Destinationpath\testing") & _
                                    Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
                            iUploadedCnt = iUploadedCnt + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            lblUploadStatus.Text = "<b>" & iUploadedCnt & "</b> file(s) Uploaded."
            lblFailedStatus.Text = "<b>" & iFailedCnt & _
                "</b> duplicate file(s) could not be uploaded."
        Else
            lblUploadStatus.Text = "Max. 10 files allowed."
        End If
    Else
        lblUploadStatus.Text = "No files selected."
    End If
End Sub
```

Following is the error when I execute this code
Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Destinationpath\testing'.

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Comment: it shows here   Dim objFI As FileInfo() = _
                            objDir.GetFiles(Replace(Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName), _
                                Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName), "") & ".*")

Comment: have you tried using `../Destinationpath/testing` as path?